Help resolve Virtualbox install error
Trying to install Oracle virtual box on Ubuntu 22.04.4, using dpkg -i command from virtualbox-7.0_7.0.20-163906~Ubuntu~noble_avirtualbox-dkms/jammy-updates 6.1.48-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 6.1.38-dfsg-3~ubuntu1.22.04.1]md64.deb  downloaded from virtualbox site.  The installaiton is not going through, please see the error messages here and help.
root@testuser-7550:/home/testuser/Downloads# dpkg -i virtualbox-7.0_7.0.20-163906~Ubuntu~noble_amd64.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package virtualbox-7.0.
(Reading database ... 441854 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack virtualbox-7.0_7.0.20-163906~Ubuntu~noble_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking virtualbox-7.0 (7.0.20-163906~Ubuntu~noble) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of virtualbox-7.0:
 virtualbox-7.0 depends on libc6 (>= 2.38); however:
  Version of libc6:amd64 on system is 2.35-0ubuntu3.8.
 virtualbox-7.0 depends on libcurl4t64 (>= 7.16.2); however:
  Package libcurl4t64 is not installed.
 virtualbox-7.0 depends on liblzf1 (>= 1.5); however:
  Package liblzf1 is not installed.
 virtualbox-7.0 depends on libpng16-16t64 (>= 1.6.2); however:
  Package libpng16-16t64 is not installed.
 virtualbox-7.0 depends on libqt5core5t64 (>= 5.15.1); however:
  Package libqt5core5t64 is not installed.
 virtualbox-7.0 depends on libqt5dbus5t64 (>= 5.14.1); however:
  Package libqt5dbus5t64 is not installed.
 virtualbox-7.0 depends on libqt5gui5t64 (>= 5.14.1) | libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.14.1); however:
  Package libqt5gui5t64 is not installed.
  Package libqt5gui5-gles is not installed.
 virtualbox-7.0 depends on libqt5opengl5t64 (>= 5.0.2); however:
  Package libqt5opengl5t64 is not installed.
 virtualbox-7.0 depends on libqt5printsupport5t64 (>= 5.0.2); however:
  Package libqt5printsupport5t64 is not installed.
 virtualbox-7.0 depends on libqt5widgets5t64 (>= 5.15.1); however:
  Package libqt5widgets5t64 is not installed.
 virtualbox-7.0 depends on libqt5xml5t64 (>= 5.0.2); however:
  Package libqt5xml5t64 is not installed.
 virtualbox-7.0 depends on libssl3t64 (>= 3.0.0); however:
  Package libssl3t64 is not installed.
 virtualbox-7.0 depends on libstdc++6 (>= 13.1); however:
  Version of libstdc++6:amd64 on system is 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04.
 virtualbox-7.0 depends on libtpms0 (>= 0.8.0~dev1); however:
  Package libtpms0 is not installed.
 virtualbox-7.0 depends on libvpx9 (>= 1.12.0); however:
  Package libvpx9 is not installed.
 virtualbox-7.0 depends on libxt6t64; however:
  Package libxt6t64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-7.0 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.70+nmu1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (2.1-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 virtualbox-7.0

root@testuser-7550:/home/testuser/Downloads# 


why does your noble system have jammy updates on it?

@OrganicMarble why does everything the OP has in tags, etc. say 22.04 and not 24.04?  I would assume this is a case of them actually using 22.04 and not 24.04.  Nowhere did OP say they're using Noble.  Even in the edit history.

@ThomasWard that was my thought as well. An attempt to install a noble VB package on a jammy system.

The VirtualBox .deb file that you downloaded from Linux_Downloads – Oracle VM VirtualBox is labeled as ​"Ubuntu 24.04", however this .deb file is not compatible with your Ubuntu 22.04. This is the reason why you got so many dependency problems prevent configuration of virtualbox-7.0 errors. Instead of downloading the VirtualBox .deb file for Ubuntu 24.04, you should download the VirtualBox .deb file for Ubuntu 22.04 from the same webpage.
Then change directories with cd to the directory containing the file that you just downloaded, and install the .deb file that you downloaded with the following command.
sudo apt install ./virtualbox-7.0_7.0.20-163906~Ubuntu~jammy_amd64.deb

As you can see from the above command the correct .deb file to download for Ubuntu 22.04 is named virtualbox-7.0_7.0.20-163906~Ubuntu~jammy_amd64.deb where the jammy in this file's name is the codename for Ubuntu 22.04.
